# How to display text on the same line?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display text "RESET" on the same line but I can't figure it out how to do this...I know that this is easy to do, I've tried display inline , float left, but it just doesn't work.
Here's an image which would help you:
[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="kolom8">
            <h2>Partners</h2>
            <div id="nav8">
                <li><a href="#"><span class="underlined">RE</span><span class="singleunderline">S</span><span class="underlined">ET</span></a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="underlined">RE</span><span class="singleunderline">S</span><span class="underlined">ET</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="underlined">RE</span><span class="singleunderline">S</span><span class="underlined">ET</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="underlined">RE</span><span class="singleunderline">S</span><span class="underlined">ET</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="underlined">RE</span><span class="singleunderline">S</span><span class="underlined">ET</span></a></li>
            </div>
            <div id="slider8">
                <a href="#"><img id="back8" src="images/back.png" /></a>
                <a href="#"><img id="forward8" src="images/forward_blue.png" /></a>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end kolom8 -->
```

CSS:

```
/* KOLOM 8 */
#kolom8 {
    width: 1440 px;
    height: 185px;
}
#kolom8 h2 {
    margin-bottom: 38px;
}
#nav8 li {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  width: 750px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}
#nav8 a {
  color: #7b7979;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-decoration: overline;
  display: inline;

}
span.underlined 
{
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
span.singleunderline 
{
  border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
}
/* KOLOM 8 */
```

Comment: PLease provide a jsfiddle to receive solutions to your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `display: inline` in li elements. Additional you can use `text-align: center` to `div` container:

```css
/* KOLOM 8 */

#kolom8 {
  width: 1440 px;
  height: 185px;
}
#kolom8 h2 {
  margin-bottom: 38px;
}
#nav8 {
  text-align: center;
  }
#nav8 li {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  /*width: 750px;*/
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  display: inline;
}
#nav8 a {
  color: #7b7979;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-decoration: overline;
  display: inline;
}
span.underlined {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
span.singleunderline {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
}
/* KOLOM 8 */
```

```html
<div id="kolom8">
  <h2>Partners</h2>

  <div id="nav8">
    <li><a href="#"><span class="underlined">RE</span><span class="singleunderline">S</span><span class="underlined">ET</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="underlined">RE</span><span class="singleunderline">S</span><span class="underlined">ET</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="underlined">RE</span><span class="singleunderline">S</span><span class="underlined">ET</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="underlined">RE</span><span class="singleunderline">S</span><span class="underlined">ET</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="underlined">RE</span><span class="singleunderline">S</span><span class="underlined">ET</span></a>
    </li>
  </div>
  <div id="slider8">
    <a href="#">
      <img id="back8" src="images/back.png" />
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img id="forward8" src="images/forward_blue.png" />
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
<!-- end kolom8 -->
```

Comment: Should really remove the width for the `li`, at this point it is useless

Comment: Right, I put that width and height just for trying to arrange the text